# How to use relationship value in Laravel Form Facade?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to use the values of attributes on a model's relationship with `Form::label` and `Form::text`. The `Form` helper was removed from Laravel, so I use `'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade'` instead.

Here is the relationship in the `Order` Model:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Order extends \Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function account_number()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Account_number', 'product_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

And here's the Blade template with `Form`. The text in the `account_number` `<td>` will show:

```
{"id":4,"user_id":52,"account_type":"alipay","account_no":"xxxxxx","account_name":"xxxxxx","phone":"xxxxxx","created_at":"2017-11-15 14:43:51","updated_at":"2017-11-15 14:43:51","deleted_at":null}
```

```
{!! Form::model($order, array('files' => true)) !!}
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td>{!! Form::label('out_trade_no', 'out_trade_no: ') !!}</td>
  <td>{!! Form::text('out_trade_no')!!}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{!! Form::label('account_number', 'account_number: ') !!}</td>
  <td>{!! Form::text('account_number')!!}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I want to show inputs for each `account_number` attribute separately, not as a JSON string.

I have tried with:

```
<tr>
  <td>{!! Form::label('account_number.id', 'account_number: ') !!}</td>
  <td>{!! Form::text('account_number.id')!!}</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
  <td>{!! Form::label('account_number->id', 'account_number: ') !!}</td>
  <td>{!! Form::text('account_number->id')!!}</td>
</tr>
```

or

```
<tr>
  <td>{!! Form::label('account_number', 'account_number: ') !!}</td>
  <td>{!! Form::text('account_number["id"]')!!}</td>
</tr>
```

...but none of these work. They all leave this `<td>` empty.

Comment: What you are looking for is something like a nested form( I guess ) where you can insert a part of the form in 1 table and some in other) but it seems laravel does not support it directly so you will have to look for a workaround..you may look at this for reference..https://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-work-around-for-nested-forms

Comment: @DhavalChheda your links is another workarount. I want to use the relationship with form facade here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do something more in-depth understanding.

While generating a text input element, [FormBuilder](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/master/src/FormBuilder.php#L268) will look for the value in the session for the value in the old input data then it'll look in the model instance if one is set. Otherwise it'll just use empty.
Before it gets the appropriate value, it will transform the key which we specified, such as `account_number.id`, `account_number->id`, `account_number["id"]`. Focus on the [transformKey](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/master/src/FormBuilder.php#L1256) function

```
protected function transformKey($key)
{
    return str_replace(['.', '[]', '[', ']'], ['_', '', '.', ''], $key);
}
```

Let's call it with the keys you specified one by one:

1. `account_number.id`    => `account_number_id`
2. `account_number->id`   => `account_number->id`
3. `account_number["id"]` => `account_number."id"`

Then it will split the key by `.` return a array `$keys`. And check if exists nested model with `$keys[0]`, otherwise return the value of master model with transformed key. [getFormValue()](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/master/src/Eloquent/FormAccessible.php#L24)

No matter it exists nested model or not, it will get the value through [data_get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L442) function.

Obviously, the first key and the second you specified doesn't work. The third one `account_number."id"`, it will find the nested model successfully but it won't retrieve the attribute through the way `$nestedModel->{"id"}`. Use `account_number[id]` instead, it works well.

```
<td>{!! Form::text('account_number[id]')!!}</td>
```

Answer (score 5):

To create input controls for a model's relationships using the [`FormBuilder` tools](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html) provided by [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/), use the following syntax:

```
{!! Form::model($order, ...) !!} 
    ...
    {!! Form::label('account_number[id]', 'account number: ') !!}
    {!! Form::text('account_number[id]') !!}
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Note the lack of quotation marks around `id`. The example in the question contains quotes around the related model's `id` attribute, which breaks this magic. The code above renders the following input element using the value of the `id` attribute on the `Order` model's `account_number` relationship:

```
<input name="account_number[id]" type="text" value="4">
```

The format shown in the input element's `name` attribute enables PHP to parse the POST data as an array. We can fetch the value submitted to a controller method like in this example:

```
public function save(Request $request) 
{
    $accountNumber = $request->get('account_number'); 

    echo $accountNumber['id']; // '4'
    ...
}
```

This feature is important—`FormBuilder` generates input elements designed to work with PHP's automatic grouping of request data into arrays. If we submit multiple input elements on a form for a model's relationship, Laravel makes it easy to save the result:

```
public function update(Request $request, $orderId) 
{
    Order::with('account_number')->find($orderId)
        ->fill($request->all())
        ->account_number->fill($request->account_number)
        ->push();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using [LaravelCollective](https://laravelcollective.com/)'s FirmBuilder with model binding is wrong.
Let's suppose you have data in orders like:

```
{
id: 1,
....., // some other fields
account_number: {
 "id":4,
 "user_id":52,
 "account_type":"alipay",
 "account_no":"xxxxxx",
 "account_name":"xxxxxx",
 "phone":"xxxxxx",
 "created_at":"2017-11-15 14:43:51",
 "updated_at":"2017-11-15 14:43:51",
 "deleted_at":null
}
}
```

So now if you want to display account_number `id` in textfield then you can write your form builder in this way:

```
{!! Form::model($order, ...) !!} 
    ...
    <tr>
    <td>{!! Form::label('account_number', 'account number: ') !!}</td>
    <td>{!! Form::text('account_number', $order->account_number->id) !!}</td>
    </tr>
    ...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

or

```
<td>{!! Form::text('account_number[id]') !!}</td>
```

But in the second answer you'll get issue when submitting form. Because besides getting the value you wanted, that line of code also renames your input name attributes' value to `account_number[id]` instead of `account_number`. So the best option is to use the first solution. Here is the link for form model binding in LaravelCollective : https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#form-model-binding

Comment: Here you use specify a default value for the form input. When the input is not defined, the default value will be used. Set the default value is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

After trying to implement on my own **environment**, my conclusion-

```
{!! Form::model($order, array('files' => true)) !!}
 <table border="1">
   <tr>
     <td>{!! Form::label('out_trade_no', 'out_trade_no: ') !!}</td>
     <td>{!! Form::text('out_trade_no')!!}</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>{!! Form::label('account_number', 'account_number: ') !!}</td>
     <td>{!! Form::text('account_number[id]')!!}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```